# Moq is not calling abstract methods

Tags: c#, moq, abstract-class, abstract, factory-pattern

I have some code in my application that uses an abstract factory pattern: An abstract class that has an abstract dependency. The concrete dependency shall be delivered by the concrete class right in the constructor of the abstract class. However, when I want to mock the concrete class, Moq never calls the concrete implementation. Code is below:

```
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace Example
{
    public abstract class AbstractClass
    {
        public AbstractDependency Dependency { get; private set; }

        protected AbstractClass()
        {
            // This constructor is called by Moq
            Dependency = CreateDependency();    
        }

        protected abstract AbstractDependency CreateDependency();
    }

    public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
    {
        // Problem: This method is not called by Moq
        protected override AbstractDependency CreateDependency()
        {
            return new ConcreteDependency();
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractDependency
    {
    }

    public class ConcreteDependency : AbstractDependency
    {
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // The following passes. The concrete implementation of CreateDependency is called!
            ConcreteClass concreteClass = new ConcreteClass();
            Assert.NotNull(concreteClass.Dependency);

            // The following fails. When code is run with the mock the concrete implementation of CreateDependency is not called!
            Mock<ConcreteClass> concreteClassMock = new Mock<ConcreteClass>();
            Assert.NotNull(concreteClassMock.Object.Dependency);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is that? I would think Moq should be able to resolve the concrete class and instantiate it. And how can I fix it without changing the production code?

Comment: BTW calling virtual methods in constructor is considered as design flaw and can be dangerous. See e.g. [this FxCop rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2214-do-not-call-overridable-methods-in-constructors?view=vs-2017).

Comment: You should never call a virtual method from a base class constructor! Your design is fundamentally broken because of that. (You *can* get away with it, but if the virtual method implemented in the derived class relies on anything that is initialised in the derived class's constructor, it will blow up. That is not a problem for the code you posted here, though.)

Comment: Bad design aside, You did not let moq know that it should call base members ie `Mock<ConcreteClass> concreteClassMock = new Mock<ConcreteClass>() { CallBase = true };`

Comment: Ideally, you should not even be mocking concrete implementations. Leads me to think that this is part of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: OK, I was not aware about calling virtual methods from a constructor was a design smell. I will change it so the problem will not arise in the first place. Apart from that: The hint from @Nkosi indeed fixes the code above.

Comment: As soon as Moq has the possibility, it will override a member and use an "empty" implementation that returns null/empty/default (after some Moq rule; this is for _loose_ mocks). @Nkosi is absolutely right you can use `CallBase` to instruct Moq to not mock, but rather call the actual base implementation. Another option is to seal the member (`protected sealed override AbstractDependency CreateDependency() { … }`) in which case Moq cannot override it, and the implementation of your class will be used. But of course, as others have said, you design may be dubious.